In 5 a side Is it illegal for a goalie whilestandong in the area throw the ball out where his hands go over the line with the ball or is it allowed
If the goalie is within his area in 5 a side football, throws the ball out to a player and his hands go past the line with the ball but his feet remain in the area not past the line is that allowed or a penalty to the opposition?
